# Rails form_for Error - Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get user input and update a field in a model.

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: users_bankacc_path(current_user.id), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
       <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %><i> (as in your bank account)</i>
          <%= f.text_field :bankaccname, class:"form-control" %>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is my method in the controller:

```
def bankacc(id)
   user = User.find(params[:id])
   user.update_attributes(:bankaccname)
end
```

I get an error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)".

Comment: Shouldn't it be `form_for(` since you are closing it at the end with `) do` ?

Comment: I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller action methods should not be defined with any arguments. They're expected to get whatever context information they need from the `params` structure, something you're already doing with the `find` call.

Removing `(id)` from the method signature should fix this.

What's incorrect is calling `update_attributes` with only a symbol. The general usage is:

```
user.update_attributes(bankaccname: params[:bankaccname])
```